# In Tensorflow how to freeze saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tflearn

This is probably a very basic question...

But how do I convert checkpoint files into a single .pb file.
My goal is to serve the model using probably C++

These are the files that I'm trying to convert.

[image: Checkpoints]

As a side note I'm using tflearn with tensorflow.

**Edit 1:**
I found an article that explains how to do this: https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc

The problem is that I'm stuck with the following error

```
KeyError: "The name 'Adam' refers to an Operation not in the graph."
```

How do I fix this?

**Edit 2:**
Maybe this will shed some light on the problem.

[image: Regression Layer]

The error that I get comes from the regression layer, if I use: `sgd`.
I'll get

```
KeyError: "The name 'SGD' refers to an Operation not in the graph."
```

Comment: you an solve the same referring. https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial on https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc **works just fine**.

The problem was that I was loading the model using tensorflow instead of using tflearn.

So... instead of:

```
tf.train.import_meta_graph(...)
```

We do:

```
model.load(...)
```

TFLearn knows how to parse the graph properly.

Comment: `model.load(...)?` can you explain more?

Comment: model.load(...) comes from TFLearn itself not Tensorflow.

I was mixing the two APIs.

Comment: Check here: http://tflearn.org/#quick-overview, in the first code example they create a model doing `model = tflearn.DNN(net)`.
From that you can do `model.load`

Comment: This one asks to build network from scratch, I wanted to keep model built by a program and later have a difference program just to call the model from predictions. Not getting easy way to just import these tflearn generated files(meta,index...)