# How to import(restore) Neural network model built by tflearn from files

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, text-classification, tflearn

I am referring to [this tutorial](https://sourcedexter.com/tensorflow-text-classification-python/) on text classification and built a custom training set for a text classification.

I am saving the model with below code.

```
# Define model and setup tensorboard
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
```

This generates below files.

```
model.tflearn.data-00000-of-00001
model.tflearn.index
model.tflearn.meta
tflearn_logs folder
```

I want to use the model built in different iteration for testing purpose.

I tried ,

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.tflearn.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

*but I get;*

> **KeyError: "The name 'adam' refers to an Operation not in the graph."** error

I know [from documentation](http://tflearn.org/getting_started/#weights-persistence) that `tflearn.DNN(network).load('file_name')` loads a model , but we need to create and pass the network instance, to build a network we again go through same code from scratch which takes time since it will do training which I want to avoid.

Code for building network

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
```

`tflearn.input_data` has shape input as mandatory , so we would again need training data to be fed again.So it causes rebuilding model.
I checked the documentation , could not find what I need (2-3 lines of code which would import build neural network model to save retraining time.

Please let me know if you guys know solution for this.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595646/in-tensorflow-how-to-freeze-saved-model/46637498?noredirect=1#comment87414509_46637498) but its not duplicate

- OP was facing issue while building neural net during building tree , while I am facing issue importing build model.
- Tutorial mentioned in the answer does not have tflearn NN model import

Comment: Reason for random down-vote? whoever voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to restore the saved model with below code.

`tflearn` can restore model from saved log and model files.

### Create dummy neural net of same size as saved model

Note : You may need to keep track of previously saved model's weights (size of input training and corresponding classes)

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, train_x[0]])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8, restore=False)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8, restore=False)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, train_y[0], activation='softmax', restore=False)
dnn = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
```

### Load the saved model on to DNN

```
model = dnn.load('./model.tflearn')
```

Use the loaded model for predictions

```
test_data = ###converted data 
model.predict(test_data)
```